# Handling find_or_create_by race conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

As many know, this is susceptible to race conditions a la simultaneous requests.

One solution is to:

`validates :unique_id, uniqueness: true`

and then

```
begin
  Model.find_or_create_by(attributes)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
  retry
end
```

Is there another way without a uniqueness constraint? This is an action that happens often, and if I'm not mistaken, the uniqueness constraint requires a run through the entire DB table each time, which IMO is slow.

Answer (score 0):

The right way is adding UK on "unique_id" which will using BTree Index, that mean not slow OR you can use optimistic lock